# Script Stopped working after PHP5 > PHP7.2?

Tags: javascript, php

I came across this problem recently that I have no idea what caused it. This script makes my wp custom taxonomy list act like a tree accordion menu, but this script broke - I had to find out through a member of the site.

I am too far ahead into updating the site to be able to turn back time. However 1 major thing I did was upgrade from PHP5 to PHP7.2 on the server so I am not sure if that broke it. Here is the script in question:

```
<script>
function addExpandCollapse(id, expandSym, collapseSym, accordion)  {jQuery('#' + id + ' .expand').live('click', function() {
if (accordion==1) {
  var theDiv =        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span.collapse').parent().find('div');
  jQuery(theDiv).hide('normal');
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span.collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
    createCookie(theDiv.attr('id'), 0, 7);
}
jQuery('#' + id + ' .expand .sym').html(expandSym);
expandCat(this, expandSym, collapseSym);
return false;
  });
jQuery('#' + id + ' .collapse').live('click', function() {
collapseCat(this, expandSym, collapseSym);
return false;
});
}
</script>
```

The error on Safari displays

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...jQuery('#' + id + ' .expand').live...')

But this error never occurred back then so I am not sure if the code is not PHP7.2 compliant. I am really new to PHP, and fairly a student to Javascript. Any advice?

Comment: this is js, nothing to do with your php version.

Comment: Tim is right, In the provided code there is only Javascript content.
perhaps there is a place in your code that JS interact with a php resonse ?, If yes please show your code.

Comment: Did you by any chance upgrade jQuery as well? Because I notice this code uses [the `.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Thanks to @IMSoP I managed to figure it out. I installed a plugin that disabled the jquery migrate which is why .live was no longer working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try change .live('click') to .on('click')

Comment: This was it. Thanks Ulugbek!

Comment: Sorry, just double checked it. The error is now gone, but with this, the 3rd level of the tree now does not open, and instead just opens that taxonomy. Normally it opens all subcategories 3 levels deep before it links. I am just trying to figure out what .live did instead of .on

Comment: .live()  deprecated after 1.7 version. 
jQuery 1.7+ need use .on() or .bind()